# My website is being forward to another URL off the search engine links

Tags: url, url-rewrite, redirection

When you type my website in the address bar you make your way to our website.  But if you Google or Yahoo us and click on the link they provide as a search result you get forwarded to another URL that has nothing to do with us.

I've searched Magento admin-dashboard high and low with no success.  I've tried the URL redirects with no luck.

Any idea to figure out?

Thanks in advance.

-John.

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess? without knowing the url its hard to see what the issue is but your htaccess would be my first recommendation

Comment: Have you tried from another pc? Does it redirect for other URLs or just yours?

Answer (score 2):

Do below things and update in comment:

1. Check `.htaccess`
2. Check `index.php` (Redirection can be done from here too)
3. Check in ADMIN Panel
4. Check in hosting if site is redirected to another URL

Comment: excuse my ignorance but there is no hosting in my ADMIN panel.  I go through my Magento Dashboard --> Configuration -->  Advanced -->  Admin and I don't see hosting.  I'm a newbe and some hacks are taking advantage.  Also I don't even know where or how to access my .htaccess.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Hosting is where your site is hosted. You need to access Cpanel. This is where all of your files located. In all files, there will be a file .htaccess and you need check in this file. You are newbe so its advised to look for some professional because its quite difficult if you are not even aware about hosting.